# $\sigma$-field generated by random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

If we have 
$$ P(Y_i=1)=\frac{1}{2} , \, P(Y_i=-1)=\frac{1}{2} \text{ for } i=1,2, $$
and describe $$X=Y_1+Y_2$$
then what is $\sigma$-field $X$ ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ denotes a random variable defined on probability space $\langle\Omega,\mathcal A\rangle$ then: $$\sigma(X)=\{\{X\in B\}\mid B\in\mathcal B\}$$ where $\mathcal B$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets on $\mathbb R$.

If moreover $\{X\in C\}=\Omega$ where $C$ denotes a countable subset of $\mathbb R$ then: $$\sigma(X)=\{\{X\in D\}\mid D\subseteq C\}\tag1$$

This because  $\{X\in D\}\in\sigma(X)$ for every $D\subseteq C$, and conversely the RHS of $(1)$ is evidently a $\sigma$-algebra that contains every set $\{X\in B\}=\{X\in B\cap C\}$ for $B\in\mathcal B$.

Further the countability of $D$ tells us that: $$\{X\in D\}=\bigcup_{d\in D}\{X=d\}$$

In your case there is actually not enough information.

Things would be different under the extra conditions that $\{Y_1\in\{-1,1\}\}=\Omega=\{Y_2\in\{-1,1\}\}$.

So not $Y_i\in\{-1,1\}$ *almost surely*, but instead $Y_i(\omega)\in\{-1,1\}$ *for every* $\omega\in\Omega$.

Under that condition we have $\{X\in C\}=\Omega$ for $C=\{-2,0,2\}$.

Note that this set has $8$ subsets $D$ and for every such $D$ we can find an expression for $\{X\in D\}$ in terms of the $Y_i$.

For instance $\{X\in\{-2,2\}\}=\{Y_1=Y_2\}$.

Comment: thanks for your help is this true?
$$\sigma(X)=\{0,2,-2,\{2,-2\},\{2,0\},\{-2,0\},\Omega\}$$

Comment: No. elements of $\sigma(X)$ are subsets of $\Omega$. E.g. $2$  cannot be recognized as a subset of $\Omega$. No information is given about $\Omega$. You can at most express the elements of $\sigma(X)$ in $Y_1,Y_2$, and this only if the extra condition mentioned in my answer is satisfied.